# Screenshot : RasterFormatException (y+ height) is outside Raster

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, screenshot

Using Selenium Webdriver to take screenshot for specific UI Element as suggested by other post, I am using getSubimage method to capture the screenelement. But, receiving failure exception.

I am unsure about the difference in uielement's getLocation().getX() and getSize().getWidth().getX(). If someone can clarify this, as inside the WritableRaster method's condition it always checks for y+height

```
File imgSrc=((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        Point point = uiElem.getLocation();    
         Point bottomright = new Point(uiElem.getSize().getWidth(),
                 uiElem.getSize().getHeight());             
          int xcord = point.getX();
          int ycord = point.getY();  

          BufferedImage img;
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(imgSrc);
             BufferedImage dest = img.getSubimage(xcord, ycord, bottomright.getX(), bottomright.getY());
              ImageIO.write(dest, "png", imgSrc);       
              FileUtils.copyFile(imgSrc, new File(".\\Screenshots\\123.png"));          
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

While debugging, I noticed that the img (width 1366 and height = 613). and getSubImage() has (194,1335,960,15). It will always fail for condition (y+ height) >(this.minY + this.height ) inside createWritableChildMethod. So,can anyone point,where it's going wrong, also it doesn't make sense , as why we adding (y+height)of sub-image is greater?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround, just notices it's better to use getScreenshotAs() directly on UIElement without doing alot of manipulation on the element.

```
public void takeSmallScreenshot(WebDriver driver, WebElement uiElem)
{
         File uiElementSrc = uiElem.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
         try {
            FileUtils.copyFile(uiElementSrc, new File(".\\Screenshots\\"+uiElem.getText().substring(0,5)+".png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
```